# iOS share extension pushViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm following this tutorial to create a share extension like this:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mini-hacks/tree/master/ios-share-extension

[image]

My problem is i want the pushed view controller screen to be able to spread the whole screen like the skype app on iOS.

[image]

Please help show me where can i customize this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using auto layout? BTW, it's *not* the "view controller" that you want to extend through the full screen vertically - it's the view controller's *view*. And you probably need to alter the table view's constraints to achieve what you want.

Comment: i'm using auto layout to pin the view to edges of superview's view. What i am confused is that the pushed view controller is laid-out using the Share extension default layout of iOS and how should i change that?